# R cluster analysis Ward auto deleting outliers

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, outliers

How can I code in R to duplicate cluster analyses done in SAS which involved 
method=Ward and the TRIM=10 option to automatically delete 10% of the cases as outliers? (This dataset has 45 variables, each variable with some outlier responses.)

When I searched for R cluster analysis using Ward's method, the trim option was described as something that shortens names rather than something that removes outliers.

If I don't trim the datasets before the cluster analysis, one big cluster emerges with lots of single-case "clusters" representing outlying individuals.  With the outlying 10% of cases automatically removed, 3 or 4 meaningful clusters emerge.  There are too many variables and cases for me to remove the outliers on a case-by-case basis.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't provided any information on how you want to identify outliers. Assuming the simplest case of removing the top and the bottom 5% of cases of every variable (i.e. on a variable by variable basis), you could do this with [`quantile`](http://www.r-tutor.com/elementary-statistics/numerical-measures/percentile) function.

Illustrating using the example from the link above, you could do something like:

```
duration = faithful$eruptions
duration[duration <= quantile(duration,0.95) & duration > quantile(duration,0.05)]
```

Comment: Thank you for your insights.  One problem here is that the automatic SAS trimming of outliers seems to be a black box, so duplicating it is a mystery.    It seems like the best thing to do in the future is to be explicit about how outliers were identified and deleted.

Comment: @TomSLC Certainly, that can be a problem with proprietary software, though sometimes one can get some insight by reading the manual. Reading the [documentation](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/statug/63033/HTML/default/viewer.htm#statug_cluster_sect004.htm) on `TRIM` function, it seems as though a more sophisticated procedure is involved, but I failed to grasp what it was.