# How to convert a cluster analysis from SAS (with ward method and auto deleting outliers) to R?

Tags: r, sas, cluster-analysis, outliers

A similar question has been asked few years ago [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29580999/r-cluster-analysis-ward-auto-deleting-outliers) but stayed unanswered/unsolved so I try my chance again.

I'm trying to code and duplicate in R, cluster analyses done in SAS that involved the Ward method and the Trim option. This trim option automatically omits points with low probability densities (outliers). Densities are estimated by the kth-nearest-neighbor or uniform-kernel method. This option is runned during the clustering analysis.

My goal is to find the same clustering method including this trimmming option in R because I have to complement my dataset with new datas. I thus want to be sure my cluster analysis in R are right and follow similarly what was done in SAS.

So far, as my dataset is composed of mixed variables, I have computed a Gower dissimiliraty matrix. Then, I tried different clustering ways:

1. the usual one from 'cluster' package (hclust with ward method) => worked well but I can't find any function to deal with outliers during the analysis.
2. partitionning clustering from 'TraMineRextras' (pam with ward method). => Outliers can be removed but only once the cluster are identified so it gives a different results from the one from SAS.
3. density-based clustering algorithm from 'dbscan' package. => worked well (good numbers of cluster and identifications of outliers) but the clustering analysis is not using the ward method. So I can't rely on this method to reproduce the exact same analysis from SAS.

Does anyone know how to proceed or would have ideas to reproduce the trimming from SAS in R?

Many thanks !

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for the agnes function in the cluster package.  Documentation can be found here: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/cluster/cluster.pdf